# javascript error: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to find the reason why my code doesnt work, and chrome comes back with this eror:
Uncaught ReferenceError: calcMPG is not defined...
Can someone spot my mistake ?(desperate)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcMPG() {
        document.calc.startingMileage.value = startMileage;
        document.calc.endingMileage.value = endMileage;
        document.calc.gallonsUsed.value = gallUsed;
        var MPG = (endMileage - startMileage) / gallUsed;
        if (isNAN(startMileage) || isNAN(endMileage) || isNAN(gallUsed)) alert('please type in numbers only!');
        else document.calc.milesPerGalon.value = MPG;
    }
</script>

<form name="calc">Starting mileage:
    <input type="text" value="0" name="startingMileage" onchange="calcMPG()">
    <br>Ending mileage:
    <input type="text" value="0" name="endingMileage" onchange="calcMPG()">
    <br>Gallons used:
    <input type="text" value="0" name="gallonsUsed" onchange="calcMPG()">
    <br>Miles per galon:
    <input type="text" value="0" name="milesPerGalon">
</form>
```

Comment: startMileage is undefined. Full code please.

Comment: When I run this, I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: startMileage is not defined", not calcMPG as you specified.

Comment: What's `startMileage`, `endMileage` and `gallUsed` ?

Comment: I'd get some jQuery into the mix and use listeners instead of onChange attrs. And of course, those listeners wouldn't trigger until the DOM is ready.

Comment: It's `isNaN`, not `isNAN`.

Comment: @Dmitry there is no more code. short and simple.
Why it doesnt give me result at the end ?

Comment: ok, so you need get value like var startMileage = document.calc.startingMileage.value; and so on, would be correct way

Comment: @j08691 i'va changed it, but code still wont work

Comment: Read all the comments. You need to init your variables and change isNAN to isNAN and it works fine.

Comment: thank you guys. My mistake was NAN and variable declared incorectly.

Comment: Worked code http://jsfiddle.net/J4BMj/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your declarations are wrong please correct them.

```
var startMileage = document.calc.startingMileage.value ;
var endMileage =  document.calc.endingMileage.value;
var gallUsed =  document.calc.gallonsUsed.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
startMileage
```

and your other right side references don't mean anything, they are undefined variables.

Give your inputs an id and fetch the values from them like this:

```
var startingMileage = document.getElementById('startingMileage').value;
```

Comment: should be `document.getElementById('startingMileage').value;`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, correct, I made too much haste there. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you do that, but try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcMPG(){
    var startMileage  = document.calc.startingMileage.value,
        endMileage    = document.calc.endingMileage.value,
        gallUsed      = document.calc.gallonsUsed.value,
        MPG           = (endMileage - startMileage) / gallUsed;

      if(isNaN(startMileage) || isNaN(endMileage) || isNaN(gallUsed)){
        alert('please type in numbers only!');
      } else {
        document.calc.milesPerGalon.value = MPG;
      }
    }
</script>
<form name="calc">
    Starting mileage:<input type="text" value="0" name="startingMileage" onchange="calcMPG()"><br>
    Ending mileage:<input type="text" value="0" name="endingMileage" onchange="calcMPG()"><br>
    Gallons used:<input type="text" value="0" name="gallonsUsed" onchange="calcMPG()"><br>
    Miles per galon:<input type="text" value="0" name="milesPerGalon">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4BMj/)

```
 function calcMPG(){
        var startMileage = document.calc.startingMileage.value;
        var endMileage = document.calc.endingMileage.value;
        var gallUsed = document.calc.gallonsUsed.value;

        var MPG = (endMileage - startMileage) / gallUsed; 

        if(isNaN(startMileage) || isNaN(endMileage) || isNaN(gallUsed))
            alert('please type in numbers only!');
        else 
            document.calc.milesPerGalon.value = MPG;
    }
```